# Windows desktop issue: pointer 'prints' on the screen

Tags: windows-10, mouse-cursor, dwm

I've recenly installed windows 10 on my dell XPS15 (L501X).
I have this issue: at random times, the mouse pointer 'prints' on the screen the scroll icon, overimpressed on any opened program, and the only way I found to reset is by kiling `dwm.exe` to have the desktop repainted.

Does someone have had my same issue, how could I solve this (other than rolling back to win7).

Attached picture shows the 'printed' pointer surrounded by a yellow circle:

Edit: I forgot the picture, here it is

[image]

EDIT:
I found that the issue comes after few time of firefox usage, chrome does not seem to give this issue.

Comment: Post edited, picture added.

Comment: That's not the usual cursor. Is it always this cursor that gets painted? Do you have any software installed that customizes the cursor or mouse?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a mouse cursor: it looks more like a detached scroll-bar. Have you tried `F5` to repaint the screen?

Comment: The cursor that 'stucks' is always that, no I don't have any cursor customization. It seems to appear randomly. Next time it happens I'll try F5